# Blender automatic weights

Tags: mesh, rigging, bones

During adding automatic weights to my model something went wrong and I don't know what. I'm stucked in 10:16 of this tutorial.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cGvalWG8HBU

[image: Blender]

Comment: What do you mean by "wrong" ? The vertex on the right shoulder ?